# Busybox than black screen only. No

Tags: settings, boot

First I has problem with busybox,

Today my Asus laptop (ultrabook ux21A asus) keep ask to log in at terminal. And I can not use my Hera as this far.
[image]

thanks advance for your help.

Comment: You installed something that broke the graphical interface. The only solution is to revert that package. Otherwise you'd need to backup your data and do a full reinstall.

Comment: thanks for solution, I a new user for linux, please guide me how to backup my data? since I can not move from terminal? everything black. anyway I use Elementary OS 5.1.7

Comment: Do you have the USB stick or DVD from which you installed elementary? You can load it and copy the files that you need.

Comment: yes i have a usb, but i can't access the normal screen, when i turn on the laptop, i can only see a black terminal like the picture above, but the linux logo appeared before

Comment: You need to plug in the usb, turn on the laptop and press F12 quickly (multiple times) until you see the selector to boot from the USB.

Comment: to make a backup is the usb empty?

Comment: No no. You need a bootable USB (USB with elementary, to reinstall elementary). From that USB you can copy/paste your files.

Comment: thanks in advance, when reinstalling there will be a command to backup old files? ok, I will prepare elementary, using rufus, right?

Comment: Yes, use rufus. You need to open "try elementary" or "DEMO mode" and from there find your files and copy them.